# RT_preempt? Has the development of RT_preempt patch been stopped?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, real-time, patch

I am looking for some contribution for real time linux which majorly involves RT_PRREMPT patch .
The wiki page of RT are pretty old i,e it says its been updated last at 2008

Also there are no wish list or bug list specific to RT _Preempt

Even bug zilla also doesn't have much on rt preempt?

Any resource pointing towards bugs ,features that are to be added to RT_preempt would be a lot of help.

Comment: Look at the [mailing list](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-rt-users/) and you'll see it is alive and kicking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thankfully, it does seem to be alive and well.
I can understand your tension: on 21 Oct 2014, an LWN article - [The future of the realtime patch set](http://lwn.net/Articles/617140/) - quoted Thomas Gleixner at less-than-highly-optimistic regarding the future of the PREEMPT_RT project.

The good news: recently, as of 05 Oct 2015, LF seems to have a working group in place for RT Linux.

Additional info here:
[The Linux Foundation Announces Project to Advance Real-Time Linux](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/announcements/2015/10/linux-foundation-announces-project-advance-real-time-linux)
By Linux_Foundation - October 5, 2015 – 8:14am

and here:

[Real-Time Linux on the go, OSADL](https://www.osadl.org/Single-View.111+M5c0795180e5.0.html)
(quoting from the article)
“… OSADL is looking forward to a fruitful collaboration in the Linux Foundation RTL Working Group. We very much hope that a day will come in the foreseeable future when Linux mainline will immediately contain - without any further patching - the PREEMPT_RT configuration option. And we can only appeal to the other members of the RTL Working Group to not let Linux users wait too long. OSADL certainly will continue to go for it.”